# How can I get the mean out of every 8 values in an array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, mean

Goal: Getting the mean value of every 8 values so that the "arrayfinal" is reduced by factor 8.

Example:
Let's say we have an array which looks like following:
array = [2 4 6 7 1 5 8 3 9 5 5 8 7 7 2 3 4 3 5 8 6 9 0 1]; % an array with 24 values

arrayfinal = [4.5 5.75 4.5];

How is the code to get from "array" to "arrayfinal"?

Best wishes,
Johannes

Comment: arrayfinal = mean(reshape(array,8,[]))